# Easy python framework with fields and drop downs

Tags: python, python-requests, frameworks

I’d like to code a simple and easy script in python that would also use a graphical interface or framework to enter data either **manually** or with **drop down menus** like:

- months
- calendar weeks
- date ranges
- number of days
- budget

And then have a script in the « backend » to divide these data points in an excel file or CSV.

For **example** dividing a budget for 10 days would provide 10 rows with each 1/10 of the budget with the dates entered. 
This is a very simple example but the final thing I’m trying to go for would be less trivial.

I’m a total beginner in Python so I’m also seeing this as a good starter/pet project.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into tkinter.
It will allow you to create easy-to-manage GUIs behind which you can put some python code to run for your input. But without any code or examples of input and expected output, we cannot offer you much help

Comment: Thanks @tst I dunno about the code yet but I’d like to build it around a GUI experience